# Strange Segmentation Fault in OpenCascade

Tags: c++, linux, opensuse, opencascade

I am trying to run the following simple program which uses some classes from OpenCascade library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gp_Pnt.hxx>
#include <Geom_TrimmedCurve.hxx>
#include <GC_MakeArcOfCircle.hxx>
#include <GC_MakeSegment.hxx>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double myWidth = 1.0, myThickness = 0.5;

    // Profile : Define Support Points 
    gp_Pnt aPnt1(-myWidth / 2., 0, 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt2(-myWidth / 2., -myThickness / 4., 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt3(0, -myThickness / 2., 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt4(myWidth / 2., -myThickness / 4., 0);
    gp_Pnt aPnt5(myWidth / 2., 0, 0);

    // Profile : Define the Geometry 
    Handle(Geom_TrimmedCurve) anArcOfCircle = GC_MakeArcOfCircle(aPnt2,aPnt3,aPnt4);
    Handle(Geom_TrimmedCurve) aSegment1 = GC_MakeSegment(aPnt1, aPnt2);
    Handle(Geom_TrimmedCurve) aSegment2 = GC_MakeSegment(aPnt4, aPnt5);
    printf("n So far OK!n");

    return 0;
}
```

I compile and link it using:

```
$> g++ my_sample.cxx -I/usr/include/oce/ /usr/lib/oce/lib*
```

So I include all libraries since I exactly don't know which class is in which library. This compiles and linkes fine and I can see the code runs through "So far OK!". But I have a "Segmentation Fault" ONLY AFTER the program exits. Do you have any idea?

P.S.
1- I use OpenSUSE13.1 with Yast to install the OpenCascade library from repository. 
2- I also removed the C-style #include  and "printf" statement to have pure C++ code but still have the same problem. I also used std namespace.
3- I run Valgrind and it detects that segfault happens at a Tcl read function which is deeply internal to OpenCascade library! If that's true, the entire OpenCascade lib is under question with mem leak. Is that true?